# Is $f_{+}(0)$ proper limit notation?

Tags: limits, functions, notation

Is it possible/correct notation to write the limits $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{-}}f(x)$$ $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}}f(x)$$ as $$f_{+}(0)$$ $$f_{-}(0)$$ respectively, for a function $f(x)$?

Comment: The version $f(0\pm)$ is more common. One could misinterpret it as the positive or negative part of $f$

Comment: @user251257 Thank you for the reply. If you write "yes" and add that additional information as an answer, I can mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One could misinterpret it as the positive or negative part of $f$. The version $f(0\pm)$ is more common.

Comment: Or alternatively $f(0^{\pm})$.

Comment: Thanks. As a follow-up question: would it also be correct to use $f'(0+)$ to refer to the value that the derivative takes from the positive side?

Comment: @SkeletonBow in fact, it is a common to write $f'_+(0) = \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x}$. Whereas $f'(0^+) = \lim_{x\to 0^+} f'(x)$. If $f'$ isn't continuous at $0$, they may be different.

Comment: @user251257 ah, now I understand why they used that notation in that book I read. Thank you very much for the informative reply.

Comment: @user251257 Another question popped into my mind: is it also possible to write $f(\pm\infty)$?

Comment: @SkeletonBow it is rarely used. You should explain that notation in text.